# ionic4 slide to next

Tags: ionic4, ion-slides

i want to move to next slide manually but i got error.
i tried like this:

```
<ion-slides #sliderRef pager="true" (ionSlideWillChange)="onSlideChangeStart($event)">
<ion-button (click)="slideNext()">Next</ion-button>
```

and in ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit,  ViewChildren, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

export class AppointmentPage implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('sliderRef', { static: true }) protected slides: ElementRef<IonSlides>;

constructor(){}

    async slideNext(): Promise<void> {
         await this.slides.nativeElement.slideNext();
    }
...
}
```

by calling slideNext() i have this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'slideNext' of undefined
```

Comment: maybe your are missing '()' in your HTML

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your .ts

```
moveToNext(slides){
    console.log(slides);
    slides.slideNext()
}
```

in your html

```
   <ion-slides pager="true" #theSlides>
        <ion-slide >
         <ion-button (click)="moveToNext(theSlides)">Click to go to next</ion-button>   // user click event to go to next slide    
        </ion-slide>
       <ion-slide >
         <ion-button (click)="moveToNext(theSlides)">Click to go to next</ion-button>   // user click event to go to next slide    
        </ion-slide>
     </ion-slides>
```

Comment: so i just add slides name to click handler, it work right thank you.