# ionic swiper not reacting to keyboard events

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

we have implemented an image gallery with [ion-slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) (ionic 4) which in turn utilizes [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/angular).

For some reason I can not make it listen to keyboard events, it feels like the events are cought somwhere under the hood. This is my code in a nutshell:

```html
<ion-slides #slides[options]="sliderOptions" (keyup)="handleKeyEvent($event)" >
   <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slideObjects; let i = index">
      <img [src]="slide.image.src" />
   </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Anybody knows how I can add keyboard navigation via the arrowLeft and arrowRight key?

Comment: ionslides din't have any keyUp Method. You can listen to keyUp in other way and slide you images. 
Check this for Reference. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410843/5909026

Comment: Hi @Najam, this clickhandler with next slides I have already implemented and it works well, but the keyboard listener is not firing on any element for me. On a second thought, maybe I need to have a global service, which catches this keyup events on the document and then the slide component is simply subscribing to it?

Comment: Exactly, That what I was about to propose to you. Make a service for Keyboard events and subscribe to it.